# How do I fix my makefile?

Tags: makefile, centos, ffmpeg-php

I have been trying to install ffmpeg and ffmpeg-php for weeks without success. The latest error I got on my new server is:

```
[root]# make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
[root]#
```

After searching the web and stackoverflow, it seems that I need to fix my makefile?

I am running CentOS 5 32-bit.

Any help on this problem will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error means you don't actually _have_ a makefile, so it can't really be fixed. The default makefile `make` looks for is `Makefile`. If you don't have such a file, nothing happens unless you tell make to build a specific target and it has built-in rules for it, or you specify an alternate makefile name wiht `-f`.

Comment: Your error message says **there is no makefile**. Are you even in the right directory?

Comment: @Mat Thanks Mat and Jonas. Yes, the file was hidden under a bad filename. It was Makefile.global

Comment: Then your option is `make -f Makefile.global`.

Answer (score 1):

You are going about installing ffmpeg the wrong way .. make would not work because you are not in the right directory

Easy way for installation add new repo at /etc/yum.repos.d

```
nano -w /etc/yum.repos.d/dag.repo
```

Inset

```
[dag]
name=Dag RPM Repository for Red Hat Enterprise Linux
baseurl=http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el$releasever/en/$basearch/dag
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

Then Install

```
yum install ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel
```

its as easy as that ... to install ffmpeg-php

```
wget /path/to/this/file/ffmpeg-php-0.5.2.1.tbz2

tar -xjf ffmpeg-0.5.2.1.tbz2

phpize

./configure
make
make install
```

Can you see where you use make ??? After extracting the  compressed file

Lastly PHP.INI

```
nano /etc/php.ini

[ffmpeg]
extension=ffmpeg.so
```

Sometimes you need to create new ffmpeg.ini file and php reads it automatically .. this depends on your confifuration

I hope this helps

Thanks

:)